# In iOS part of passbook,PKPassLibrary's(passbook) function passes don't work

Tags: ios, passbook

I can add my app's passbook to apple's app passbook, it worked right. When i use function passes to get the passbooks in apple's app passbook, it all ways return 0, i'm sure there have more than 1 passbooks.

My code as follow

```
PKPassLibrary *pkPassLibrary=[[PKPassLibrary alloc]init];
NSArray * arry = [pkPassLibrary passes];
```

arry always 0.Who can tell me the reason?A lot of thank.

Comment: Does your app have the proper permissions and are the passes in your passbook signed with certificates issued to your dev team?

Comment: @PassKit Yes,i can add the passbook rightly.

Comment: But are the passes in the passbook 'your' passes? You can only access passes that you have permission to access.

Comment: @PassKit there are passes of my app's in the apple's passbook app, but i can't get it.